# How to filter values from an array that was cURL'ed - JSON with .JQ

Tags: arrays, json, curl, filter, jq

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "accountId": "account001",
      "tokens": [
        "tokens1",
        "tokens2",
        "tokens3",
        "tokens4",
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

so the above is an example of what I am working with, my question is how to filter out whatever token so that I can at a glance see so has what?

I have seen a ton of other answers like this

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "items": [
        {"id": 123, "name": "thing-1"},
        {"id": 124, "name": "thing-2"},
        {"id": 125, "name": "thing-3"}
    ]
}
```

```
cat file.json | jq '.items[] | select(.name == "thing-3") | .'
```

However, as you can see the tokens don't have a .name like their example has.

Could anyone else let me know how I could take the data I have and search it to see if it has token2?

Thanks in advance for any assistance that can be provided.

Comment: What is the output you want to achieve if you found a match? What do you want to return?

Comment: not sure if I understood correctly what you are trying to accomplish. you want to check if `tokens2` is contained inside `tokens` array? if that is the case, something like this `jq '.accounts[].tokens[] | select(. == "tokens2")' file.json` will print `"tokens2"` if found, nothing if not.

Comment: Not sure, how to mark your answer correct @MarcoLucidi however, it was and thank you.

Also in doing this I understand why much better, I needed to dig into both accounts[] then tokens all the other examples just showed what it would look like going 1 deep.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use  MarcoLucidi's suggestion in the comments to solve the problem

```
jq '.accounts[].tokens[] | select(. == "tokens2")
```

Answer (score 0):

> how to filter out whatever token so that I can at a glance see so has what?
>
> Could anyone else let me know how I could take the data I have and search it to see if it has token2?

I'm not exactly sure I understand the question, but given the interpretation "How do I filter the accounts that has `"tokens2"` listed as a token?" since that would be a meaningful and not completely trivial thing you could do with the data.

Given [this jqplay snippet](https://jqplay.org/s/ToV__sOmnZ), the jq query:

```
.accounts | map(select(.tokens | index("tokens2")) | .accountId)
```

finds `["account001", "account003"]` from the following data:

```
{
  "accounts": [
    {
      "accountId": "account001",
      "tokens": [
        "tokens1",
        "tokens2",
        "tokens3",
        "tokens4"
      ]
    },
    {
      "accountId": "account002",
      "tokens": [
        "tokens3",
        "tokens4"
      ]
    },
    {
      "accountId": "account003",
      "tokens": [
        "tokens1",
        "tokens2"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

An explanation follows:

- `.accounts` reduces the document to the list of accounts.
- `... | map(select(...))` filters out the accounts for which `...` produces `null`.
- `.tokens | ...` reduces each account object to its list of tokens (`.` inside `map(...)` is each element of the accounts array being mapped over, so `.tokens` is the sub-list of that account object).
- `... | index("tokens2")` produces either a non-zero index, or `null` if the value isn't found in the list.
- Subsequently, inside the `map(...)` but outside the `select(...)`, a `... | .accountId` is applied, so each object that passes the `select(...)` filter is reduced to only its account id.

You can also experiment with how each of these work by removing certain parts:

```
.accounts | map(select(.tokens | index("tokens2")) | .accountId)
.accounts | map(select(.tokens | index("tokens2")))
[ .accounts[] | select(.tokens | index("tokens2")) | .accountId ]
```